# Format the date in Angular 9 with small letter h at the end of the date

Tags: angular, angular9

I'm using `Angular 9` with `CommonModule` `DatePipe` `transform` [method](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) like:

```
this.datePipe.transform(sumDate, 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
```

I get:

```
27/20/2020 17:20:14
```

And I need just a small letter **h** at the end of it, like:

27/20/2020 17:20:14**h**

I looked at the docs but couldn't find anything. Thanks.

Comment: `this.datePipe.transform(sumDate, 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss') + 'h';`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey that was too easy :'D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attach a letter `h` by surrounding the literal text with '

```
{{my_date | date: 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss\'h\''}}
```